# Getting a Vue.js computed to run without being part of the DOM

Tags: vue.js

I can't figure out how to get Vue.js to always evaluate a computed regardless of if I'm actually using it in the page. A simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a couple input fields which I want to influence the value of another field when either has been updated. I also want this field to be manually editable too. [Example jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k6rknwqg/)

html:

```
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="updateUsername">Just here to get the darn thing to run</p>
  <div>
    yourName:<input v-model="yourName">
  </div>
  <div>
    dogsName:<input v-model="dogName">
  </div>  
  <div>
    username:<input v-model="userName">
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
        data: {
            yourName: 'Adam',
        dogName: 'Barkster',
        userName: ''
    },
        methods: {
    },
    computed: {
        updateUsername: function(){
                this.userName = this.yourName + this.dogName;
        }
    }
});
```

This works exactly as I want it to but requires I BS the use of "updateUsername" in the html. I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: so you want to the dog name and your name is updated when manually type in something in username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `watch`:

```js
watch: { updateUsername() {} }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/k6rknwqg/2/

But it seems what you want are two watchers instead:

```js
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        yourName: 'Adam',
        dogName: 'Barkster',
        userName: ''
    },
    watch: {
        yourName: {
            handler() {
                this.userName = this.yourName + this.dogName;
            },
            immediate: true
        },
        dogName() {
            this.userName = this.yourName + this.dogName;
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/k6rknwqg/6/

Another option (watching two or more properties simultaneously):

```js
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        yourName: 'Adam',
        dogName: 'Barkster',
        userName: ''
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$watch(vm => [vm.yourName, vm.dogName].join(), val => {
            this.userName = this.yourName + this.dogName;
        }, {immediate: true})
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/k6rknwqg/11/

Comment: I think I like that first option better. The two watchers work for this case since everything is so simple but if this was a big component with 10 of these triggers each with 3 to 5 dependent variables, some overlapping and others not, you would end up with a ton of repeated code and no straightforward way to connect everything back for future code maintenance. But I suppose at that point you'd also start finding ways around having to use that pattern at all.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so. The thing is your first computed has side-effects, and, typically, computed properties don't have side effects. But I do understand multiple watchers can incur in more boilerplate. I have added a third possibility. Check the answer.

Comment: Cool, haven't seen mounted before. I'd say that checks all the boxes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Vue2, [computed properties are cached based on their dependencies. A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods).

In your example, computed property=updateUserName will be re-evaluate when either dogName or yourName is changed.

And I think it is not a good idea to update other data in computed property, you will remeber you update userName in computed property=**updateUserName** now, but after a long time, you may meet some problems why my username is updated accidentally, then you don't remember you update it in one of the computed properties.

Finally, based on your example, I think [**watch**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) should be better.

You can define three watcher for userName, dogName, yourName, then execute your own logic at there.

```js
var main = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        yourName: 'Adam',
        dogName: 'Barkster',
        userName: 'Adam Barkster'
    },
        methods: {
    },
    computed: {
        updateUsername: function(){
           return this.yourName + this.dogName;
        }
    },
    watch: {
      dogName: function(newValue){
        this.userName = this.yourName + ' ' + newValue
      },
      yourName: function(newValue){
        this.userName = newValue + ' '+this.dogName
      },
      userName: function(newValue) {
        // below is one sample, it will update dogName and yourName 
        //  when end user type in something in the <input>.
        let temp = newValue.split(' ')
        this.yourName = temp[0]
        this.dogName = temp[1]
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="updateUsername">Just here to get the darn thing to run</p>
  <div>
    yourName:<input v-model="yourName">
  </div>
  <div>
    dogsName:<input v-model="dogName">
  </div>  
  <div>
    username:<input v-model="userName">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```